# Can I stop readonly users from starting a transaction in sql server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2012

ok, scenario is that a read only user queried a production database in a transaction (because it's safer?!?) then went off for the weekend without closing the transaction.  The obvious fix is to stop project managers with a little bit of knowledge having any access to our databases but that's not going to happen.

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...
```

then going off for lunch can cause as many issues as having update privileges.  Is there anything that can be done on either the server (sqlserver 2012) or in sqlserver management studio to limit the ability to start transactions?

Comment: Nope. You would need to have a job that monitors for long running open transactions by these users and kills the,.

Comment: thanks, will look at doing that, was hoping there might be a way of stopping problems before they start.